# I can't get this for loop with if statement to work

Tags: r

Here's my data, with columns infoemployer, inforst, and interrst. This is called tyearb.

```
                                                     infoemployer                 inforst
1                                                         Comcast               Jeff Dunn
6                                                   Cummins, Inc.       Rebekah Smith
38                                                         DaVita        Andy Nielsen
42                                                       Deloitte           Chase Russell
66                                              Duff & Phelps LLC     Tanner Anderson
76                                                 Frito-Lay Inc.     Tanner  Anderson
88                                              Intel Corporation          Jake Graff
96      J.P. Morgan- (J.P. Morgan is part of JPMorgan Chase & Co)        Andy Nielsen
97                                                         Lenovo      Nelson Anievas
98                                                        PepsiCo     Tanner Anderson
100                                              Procter & Gamble      Andee Flinders
102 Sears Holdings Corporation, formerly Sears, Roebuck & Company     Tanner Anderson
103                                       The Walt Disney Company Kylie Rothlisberger
106                                        Union Pacific Railroad          Jake Graff
116                                                          USAA       Rebekah Smith
117                                                       Walmart       Chase Russell
237                                                                              <NA>
238                                                         Apple                <NA>
239                              Brandes Investment Partners L.P.                <NA>
240                      EY (formerly known as Ernst & Young) LLP                <NA>
242                                            Grant Thornton LLP                <NA>
243                                                      KPMG LLP                <NA>
245                                                    Moss Adams                <NA>
246                                            Pariveda Solutions                <NA>
248                             PwC (PricewaterhouseCoopers, LLC)                <NA>
250                                                         RCLCO                <NA>
251                                     Strata Fund Services, LLC                <NA>
               interrst
1                  <NA>
6         Rebekah Smith
38         Andy Nielsen
42        Chase Russell
66      Tanner Anderson
76      Tanner Anderson
88           Jake Graff
96         Andy Nielsen
97       Nelson Anievas
98      Tanner Anderson
100      Andee Flinders
102     Tanner Anderson
103 Kylie Rothlisberger
106          Jake Graff
116       Rebekah Smith
117       Chase Russell
237      Austin Pollard
238      Brady Tengberg
239           Jeff Dunn
240       Rebekah Smith
242           Jeff Dunn
243      Andee Flinders
245          Jake Graff
246      Nelson Anievas
248      Nelson Anievas
250          Jake Graff
251        Andy Nielsen
```

My code is as follows:

```
levels(tyearb[,2]) <- c(levels(tyearb[,2]), levels(tyearb[,3]))

for (i in 1:length(tyearb))
  {
 if (is.na(tyearb[i,2]))
  {
    tyearb[i,2] = tyearb[i,3]
  }
  }
```

I just want to keep all of the current values in inforst, unless it is `<NA>`, then I want to insert the value of interrst. I recognize that I could just copy all of the values except for the first of interrst over to inforst, but I obviously can't do that with a much larger data set where more information will be missing.

I've looked at quite a few for and if loops together, I just can't get it to work for me. Could someone explain me through it please?

Comment: `ifelse` will work much faster here. Probably smth along the lines of: `tyearb[,2] = ifelse(is.na(tyearb[,2]), tyearb[,3], tyearb[,2]`

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it inserts all tyearb[,3] into tyearb[,2], but I think I can work with that.

Comment: Bracket placement matters

Comment: Forgot the closing bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data.table solution (which will be very quick for even very large data sets):

```
library(data.table)
DT[is.na(z), z := y]
```

where `z` is the column you are testing for `NA`, and `y` is the column you are inserting (although you can replace `y` here with any expression).